# How loop many pictures into tex document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, loops

Assume you have pictures `images=["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", ..., "50.png"];`. 
You would like to loop them to a single tex document such that you get nice captions. 
I think it may be possible with Tikz. 
Minimum pseudocode code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%images=["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", ..., "50.png"]; 
%% Loop here all images; for i in images
\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{"${i}"}
\caption{"Image "${i}"."}
%% end
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

OS: Debian 8.5
TeXLive: 2016 (not apt-get one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are lots of loop implementations, for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcount\ii
\begin{document}
%images=["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", ..., "50.png"]; 
%% Loop here all images; for i in images
\loop
\ifnum\ii<50
\advance\ii by 1
\begin{figure}
\centering% not \center!
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{\ii.png}
\caption{Image \the\ii.}
%% end
\end{figure}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Always a good idea to initialize your counter (but only necessary if you have to repeat this code later).

Comment: How can you have 8x2 structure? That is having two figures at the same row. Is this scalable for it? - - Assume you have 2 files which all have 8 pictures. Have one file images in first column and second file images in the second column.

Answer (score 9):

Since you asked for TikZ. (Well, if you're not using TikZ for anything else you can get away with loading just the `pgffor` package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,50} {
\begin{figure}
\centering% not \center!
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{\ii.png}
\caption{Image \ii.}
\end{figure}
} % closing brace for loop
\end{document}
```